# woocommerce get_available_variations doesn't work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using `$variations = $product->get_available_variations();` to get all variables of products and show them as a table in description section.
it works for most of the products but I've found a product that has 3 variations  but it shows two of them.
I've checked wp_posts table and all 3 variations are related to that parent product:

---

```
SELECT id,post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent=843 AND post_type='product_variation';
+-----+-------------+
| id  | post_parent |
+-----+-------------+
| 846 |         843 |
| 849 |         843 |
| 852 |         843 |
+-----+-------------+
```

---

but when I use `var_dump($variations);` the array returns two ID: 846 and 849.

This is full function of mine:

```
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

    global $product,$post;
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        if (count($variations)>0) { ?> 
            <div class="spb_text_column">
            <table class="sf-table standard_minimal">
                <tr>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Length (cm)</th>
                    <th>Width (cm)</th>
                    <th>Height (cm)</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <?php for ($j=0; $j < count($variations); $j++) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo ($variations[$j]['sku'])?$variations[$j]['sku']:$variations[$j]['name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $variations[$j]['length'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $variations[$j]['width'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $variations[$j]['height'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo number_format_i18n($variations[$j]['price']);?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }

}
```

please help to figure it out this problem.

Comment: Are you set product amount from back-end.? if not, set product amount.

Comment: @OmarFaruque, Yes, It's set. All variations have same settings and values except the price and the SKU

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the option 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' the stock status must also be 'instock'. In this case the SQL query should be:

```
SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
    WHERE p.ID = m.post_id
    AND p.post_parent = 843 AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND m.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND m.meta_value = 'instock'
```

Also, the filter 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations' and the filter 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock' can modify the default behavior.

Comment: All 3 variations have 100 stock and their stock statuses are "In Stock". also "Hide out of stock items from the catalog" was disabled in woocommerce setting

Comment: Are any of the filters 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations' or 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock' installed?

Comment: Also can you verify the post_status of the variation is 'publish'.

Comment: Another filter to check is 'woocommerce_variable_children_args'.

Comment: regarding filter: no, I didn't find anything in function.php file.

Comment: regarding  post_status, All of them has publish status.

Comment: How should I check `woocommerce_variable_children_args`?

Comment: Have you installed any WooCommerce related plugins or theme? The filters can be installed anywhere but usually would be in a WooCommerce related plugin or theme. Do you know how to use a debugger? get_available_variations() is a very simple function which calls WC_Product_Variable::get_children() and WC_Product_Variable::is_in_stock() also very simple functions - so I don't think there is a bug in the code - I also use get_available_variations() without any problems. I still think there is something strange about your data. Debugging can quickly isolate the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, All of the data for a variation are stored in two SQL tables - wp_posts and wp_postmeta. SELECT the rows in wp_posts by ID and the rows in wp_postmeta by post_id. Compare these rows. I think you will find a field that is different in a unusual way.

Comment: First, I've checked wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables, and couldn't find anything there. everything was same except price and sku. after that, I've desperately deleted existing variations and added them again. at this time, it works fine and it shows all 3 variations. btw, the problem is gone, but i couldn't find the root cause.